# Delete dynamically allocated memory after swapping its pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I'm relatively new to C++ and I want to understand memory management and pointers at the same time.

Let's say I have the code below

```
int* p1;
int* p2;
int* p3 = new int[some size];

p1 = p3;

std::swap(p1,p2);
```

How do I properly delete the dynamically allocated memory? Is doing `delete[] p3` enough? Should I delete `p2` too after that?

Comment: `Is doing delete[] p3 enough?` Yes. `Should I delete p2 too after that?` No.

Comment: I would advocate using C++ smart pointers from the start for any new C++ developer in 2021, unless required not to for instructional purposes.

Comment: Before the `std::swap(p1,p2);` makes sure you do `p2 = nullptr;`, or the swap will be doing undefined behavior.

Comment: Think like this: The allocated memory is a car, and some pointers that point to that memory is like several keys that open the same car. Once you destroy the car (by using a key to set a bomb) the rest of keys are useless; worst: they point to a destroyed object, so don't try to explode it again.

Comment: It does not matter by which pointer you delete dynamically allocated memory, you could use *either* of `p2` or `p3` – but not both. Once the memory is deleted *all* pointers pointing to get invalidated. Still reading before newly assigned is undefined behaviour. UB you have anyway, as you are reading the uninitialised `p2` pointer when passing to `std::swap`. To avoid, assign it a value, e. g. `nullptr`.

Comment: @Eljay overlooked that one

Comment: Generally, the number of times `new` is executed should match the number of times `delete` is executed. Just need to look out for cases when new or delete is called within other methods.

Comment: To better understand pointers, think of them as numeric variables that contain a memory address (that's what they actually are). When you `delete[] p3`, you're deleting the block of memory *pointed to* by `p3`, and not the `p3` variable itself.

Comment: @paisanco  Tyfor the advice. I've seen people mentioning smart pointers a lot and I think it's time I look into them

Comment: @Eljay Thank you for the advice. Didn't even cross my mind this could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some fuzzyness in colloquial speech when you do something like this:

```
delete x;
```

We say "we delete `x`". Strictly speaking thats wrong, because what is deleted is the object pointed to by `x`.

Every object allocated via `new`/`new[]` must be destroyed via one call to `delete`/`delete[]`. Whether you have two or more pointers to the same object does not change that.

```
int* p1 = nullptr;
int* p2 = nullptr;
int* p3 = new int[some size];      // p3 points to the array

p1 = p3;                           // p1 points to the same array

std::swap(p1,p2);                  // now p1 == nullptr, p2 points to the array
```

Note that the pointers are uninitialized in your example. Reading their values causes undefined behavior. As this isnt the crux of the question I avoided that by initializing them.

There is one array created via `new []` and it is that one array that you have to delete via `delete []`. You may not delete it twice. So either call `delete[] p3;` or `delete[] p2;`, but not both.

*PS:* Comments already mentioned smart pointers and I also suggest you to read about them. Nowadays you should not use raw owning pointers. An owning pointer is one that you need to call `delete` on, it "owns" the pointed to object. Raw pointers should only be used to "observe", ie you should never need to worry about calling `delete` (or `delete[]`) on a raw pointer. Of course you still need to take care whether the pointed to object is still alive, but that is not specific to dynamic allocation:

```
 int* p;
 { 
     int x = 42;
     p = &x;         // p points to x;
 }                   // x goes out of scope
 // here p is not a valid pointer anymore
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer since it sums up everything the comments said

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is happening here, it would help to add some debug statements, i.e:

```cpp
std::cout << p1 << " " << p2 << " " << p3 << "\n";
```

The trace will result in an output like:

```
0 0 0x15e7eb0
0x15e7eb0 0 0x15e7eb0
0 0x15e7eb0 0x15e7eb0
```

(Note that I initialized p1 and p1 to `nullptr`)

p3 initially points to some memory. After the assignment `p1 = p3`, p1 now points to the same memory address as p3. When you swap the pointers, now it's p2 that points to the same memory address as p3.

There are a couple of things to note here:

- You **must** pair `delete[]` with the corresponding `new[]` (do not call `delete` with `new[]` and so forth)
- Calling delete on an already deleted object is undefined behavior
- Calling delete on a null pointer is perfectly safe

As you can see, dealing with raw pointers and memory allocation can easily lead to pitfalls. It's generally recommended to use smart pointers, or if you have a non-owning pointer, to use abstractions like [`observer_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) to clearly indicate the pointer's purpose in the code.

Comment: Ty. Wish I could accept 2 answers at the same time. You gave me a deeper understanding I believe and a way to test these things myself